# jQuery $.ajax success runs for one time only

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to implement a single-star rating (i.e. a like button).

I want to change (toggle) the star image. The only problem it seems to have is that while using $.ajax, on **"success:"** part, the **src** attr (or anything else really, like .css) applies for **one (the first) time ONLY**! In fact, the client has to refresh the page to see the latest star image/status (which loads from the db).

---

Here's the code:

```
<script language="javascript">
    // Ajax: Star
    $("#p<?php echo $pID;?>").find('.star').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./ajax.php",
        data: "pID=<?php echo $pID;?>",
        cache: false,

        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#s<?php echo $pID;?>").attr("src",html);
        }
        });
    });
    // END OF: Ajax: Star
</script>
```

---

the php file echos back a filename which is meant to be replaced with the src attribute *(e.g. star-on.png OR star-off.png)*

So I think the question is: Why the "success: function" triggers only once?

Comment: You should use: replace language="javascript" with type="text/javascript". The second one is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Are you sure the script is correctly returning the status? For example by alerting the var `html`?

Comment: Can you post the HTML that goes along with this?

Comment: @Arif: The value of the html is either "images/star-on.png" or "images/star-off.png" (and seems to be ok)

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized what the problem is. It is due to the server side file (php) as it always evaluates the static data given from the client side file. All I need to do is refreshing the toggle's trigger on my php file.