# $.ajax run script for one time only

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

when I open a link with ajax I want to change the wibyia toolbar to refresh the facebook like button to the current webpage so I reload the wibyia script every time but it only load for one time......help

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("[href^='?id=']").click(function(){
    var linkid=$(this).attr("href");
    $(".col-1").html("<div style='text-align:center;margin-top:10px'><img  src='images/loading.gif' /> </div>");
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "index", "http://localhost:10358/"+linkid);

    $.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
     });
    $.get("/catdata/news.php"+linkid,function(result){
    $(".col-1").html(result);
    });
    $.getScript("http://cdn.wibiya.com/Toolbars/dir_1185/Toolbar_1185788/Loader_1185788.js");

    return false;

});
});
```

Comment: What have you investigated when you've debugged this code?

Comment: this link show a question related to this and the asker find the solution but he didn't write it . 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865836/jquery-ajax-success-runs-for-one-time-only?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: because it is not a generic issue. `$.ajax` runs for the exact amount of times you call it. If it doesn't run - the only reason for that is that you don't call it. No magic, but your issue.

Comment: $.ajax I tried and I tried $.getScript and didn't work too.

Comment: every time I click a link the above code executed , but the first time only the toolbar loaded

Comment: so you say each time you click - the code is executed, thus `$.get` is called. Have you checked in firebug that ajax request is sent each time? If so (I bet it is) - it means that you don't handle response properly

Answer (score 0):

Are the links you click in the element '.col-1'? If so then it doesn't work because the click event listener is only attached once and not after every ajax post.

Use .on() (jQuery version >= 1.7) or delegate() or just assign the click event handler after every ajax call.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your reply , but the problem for me about the script , after every Ajax post , I call the scritp to reload , but it loads for one time only not after every ajax post

Comment: Can you confirm the request isn't being sent using Firebug or Chrome DevTools?
Can you post a link to an example? That would make it a lot easier.

Comment: request is sent , but I googled and find that scripts load for first time only , and can't reload until page refresh , so it is impossible to reload script after ajax call.
Is is my website you can click links to see ajax calls
www.egypn.com
I wanted to load wibyia toolbar , and change the facebook like button after every ajax call.
Thanks Thomas for your reply